# Is the "logto" option in snort rule still work?

Tags: snort

I can't make it work.
I use this one line file as my.rules

```
alert tcp any any <> any any (msg:"test";sid:12345;logto:"log.txt";)
```

And run snort like

```
sudo snort -c ~/tmp/my.rules -l log
```

and after a seconds I stopped it,it says it Alerts 3 times

```
     Total:            5
===============================================================================
Action Stats:
     Alerts:            3 ( 60.000%)
     Logged:            3 ( 60.000%)
```

but when I saw the log ,there is no file named log.txt

```
ls log/
#alert  snort.log.1699453334
```

How does this rule option work?